# When querying a jpa database, is it possible to use methods like this?

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, jpql

I'm working on a jpa project where I persist multiple instances of a Band object which contains an ArrayList of Date objects.

I want to query the database to obtain Bands, which ArrayLists contain the specified Date.

Is this possible? I am aware my entire design could be bad but I'm hoping this is possible, as I am aware that you need a get method to use object parameters, so the method must be called somewhere.

I want to use something along these lines:

```
    Date d = new Date();
    List bands = em.createQuery("select b from Band b where b.dates.contains(d)").getResultList();
    //I am aware I may need to set up d as an argument.
```

This is the Band entity as requested. Assume package and imports are correct.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BAND")
public class Band extends SuperUser {
    @Column(name = "PHONENUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(name = "BIOGRAPHY")
    private String biography;
    @Column(name = "DATES")
    private ArrayList<Date> dates = new<Date> ArrayList();

    public Band() {
    }

    public Band(String n, String e, String p, String ph_no, String bio) {
        super(n, e, p);
        this.phoneNumber = ph_no;
        this.biography = bio;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String p) {
        this.phoneNumber = p;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setBoigraphy(String b) {
        this.biography = b;
    }

    public String getBiography() {
        return this.biography;
    }

    public void setDate(Date d) {
        dates.add(d);
    }

    public void cancelDate(Date d) {
        while (dates.remove(d)) {
        }
    }

    public ArrayList getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

}
```

EDIT: I got it working. I Didn't know about elementcollections and temporal types, changing the date list to:

```
@ElementCollection 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private List<Date> dates = new <Date>ArrayList();
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is "Member Of": http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection#NOT_MEMBER_OF_

```
select b from Band b where :d member of b.dates
```

Comment: Aha there's hope yet!  I am getting an error with that, without asking for the answer, I would love to know what it means: Error compiling the query [select b from Band b where :d member of b.dates], line 1, column 42: invalid collection member declaration [dates], expected collection valued association field.